# Identifier "character" is undefined

Tags: c, char, header-files

I am getting the error **identifier "character" is undefined**. I have included the header file as well and still cannot figure out the reason behind it. The screen shot of the error
[image]

The **print.c** file which contains the error

```c
#include "print.h"

const static size_t NUM_COLS = 80;
const static size_t NUM_ROWS = 25;

struct Char
{
    uint8_t character;
    uint8_t color;
};

struct Char *buffer = (struct Char *)0xb8000;
size_t col = 0;
size_t row = 0;
uint8_t color = PRINT_COLOR_WHITE | PRINT_COLOR_BLACK << 4;

void clear_row(size_t row)
{
    struct Char empty = (struct Char){
        character : ' ',
        color : color,
    };

    for (size_t col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++)
    {
        buffer[col + NUM_COLS * row] = empty;
    }
}
```

Other places the **character** is working fine, For example

```c
void print_char(char character)
{
    if (character == '\n')
    {
        print_newline();
        return;
    }

    if (col > NUM_COLS)
    {
        print_newline();
    }

    buffer[col + NUM_COLS * row] = (struct Char){
        character : (uint8_t)character,
        color : color,
    };

    col++;
}
```

The header file **print.h**

```c
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

enum
{
    PRINT_COLOR_BLACK = 0,
    PRINT_COLOR_BLUE = 1,
};

void print_clear();
void print_char(char character);
void print_str(char *string);
void print_set_color(uint8_t foreground, uint8_t background);
```

Comment: The syntax `color : color,` for designated initializers is an obsolete GNU extension, not standard C. It should be `.color = color,` in standard C.